# Create pdf of Amchart graph in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amcharts

I am creating graphs from [AmChart](https://www.amcharts.com/)s at my client-side(Angularjs)... I know how to export the chart as pdf from client side by [this](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/exporting-pdf-with-multiple-charts-and-related-info/)....but I want it to be executed from my backend code(nodejs)..how would I execute this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please refer to this: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/automate-report-generation-using-phantomjs/

It illustrates the use of PhantomJS.

Comment: It does solve my issue but if you are using typical css texts and boxes then this ignores all its css